# Rewrite controller magento

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, configuration

I need to overwrite action called _initAction from Controller:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php
```

into my own module and controller:

```
/app/code/local/Qbikz/ToolTip/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php
```

I already tried different ways to solved it:
First method where `<from>` and `<to>` I tried different combinations (Showing 404 page not found):

```
 <rewrite>
     <qbikz_tooltip_adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute>
         <from><![CDATA[#^/adminpanel/catalog_product_attribute/edit/#]]></from>
         <to>/tooltip/adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute/init/</to>
     </qbikz_tooltip_adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute>
</rewrite>
```

+

```
 <frontend>
        <routers>
            <qbikz_tooltip>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Qbikz_ToolTip</module>
                    <frontName>catalog_product_attribute</frontName>
                </args>
            </qbikz_tooltip>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Second method(Page showing with ignore my rules):

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Qbikz before="Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product">Qbikz_ToolTip_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product</Qbikz>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

In my controller I put die("ok"); But it's not showing up. Maybe somebody could help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you remember to clear the caches? Particularly the config cache?

Comment: "Rewtire controller"? What's that?

Comment: Yes, my cache if off.

Comment: Overwrite is ok ? sorry for my english =)

Comment: Guys Please answer my thread- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98758/optimize-code-in-magento-for-repeated-phtml-files-4-files-have-same-code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the second method but a bit modified. Your XML should look like this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Qbikz_ToolTip before="Mage_Adminhtml">Qbikz_ToolTip_Adminhtml</Qbikz_ToolTip>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Now create the file `Qbikz/ToolTip/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php` with this content:

```
<?php 
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php';
class Qbikz_ToolTip_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController {
   protected function _initAction(){
       //your magic here
   }
}
```

Comment: @Marius what is better to require a file, your way or require_once (Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Catalog'.DS.'Product'.DS.'AttributeController.php'); additionally I want to know whether we can rewrite block and controller in a single module or we have to write separate modules to write block and than controller.

Comment: Both ways have the same result. But if you want to be 100% politically correct use the method you mentioned. Also you can use the same module to rewrite blocks and controllers.

Comment: This seems not to work when trying to override indexAction() of Mage_Checkout :: CartController.php.

Comment: In 1.9.4.2 this is throwing an error for me. The controller throws a 404. Perhaps there's a different way to do it now? It is happening to me when overriding a checkout controller

Answer (score 0):

In my onestepcheckout extension, 
configuration file: app/code/local/Gurutheme/Onestepcheckout/etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
             <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Gurutheme_Onestepcheckout before="Mage_Checkout">Gurutheme_Onestepcheckout</Gurutheme_Onestepcheckout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

I added a controller

```
app/code/local/Gurutheme/Onestepcheckout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

for overriding Onepage core controller

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

This is basic source code of that overriding controller:

```
require_once("Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php");

class Gurutheme_Onestepcheckout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController {

}
```

The main thing that when rewrite magento controllers, we should include the original one and extend from it, it helps all native behavior before so all pre-built features would work.

Comment: Only if you rely on additional (protected) methods of the original class in your overridden actions. All actions missing in your controller will be handled by the original controller. Note that you technically don't *rewrite* the controller but *add* it to the list of handlers for a front name

Comment: Totally agree, we actually re-route it but should extend the original one for inheriting any existing code

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote enterprise wishlist controller.

In my `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <wishlist>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <namespace_modulename before="Enterprise_Wishlist">Namespace_Modulename</namespace_modulename>
                </modules>
                <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
                <frontName>shoppinglist</frontName>
            </args>
        </wishlist>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And in my `IndexController` Add below line:

```
require_once 'Enterprise/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php';

//before

class Namespace_Modulename_IndexController extends Enterprise_Wishlist_IndexController{}
```

You can also rewrite helper like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91474/33509