# Multiple Helpers in module

Tags: module, magento-1, helper

I know that if I add a helper to my module I need to declare it in `config.xml` using:

```
<helpers>
    <module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </module>
</helpers>
```

But, what if I want to add more helpers, how do I tell Magento about their existence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding

```
<helpers>
    <helper_alias>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </helper_alias>
</helpers>
```

to the config.xml you are not defining one helper.

You just define alias for calling helpers using `Mage::helper('helper_alias')` method.

According to magento code convention module name is used as helper's alias.

Actually in  tag you are defining helper prefix which will be associated with helper alias.

So

`Mage::helper('helper_alias')` is the same as `new Namespace_Module_Helper_Date`.

If you want to call some other helper.

For example `Namespace_Module_Helper_Otherhelper`, you just new to call

```
Mage::helper('helper_alias/otherhelper')
```

**Update: How to rewrite helper?**

In config.xml you can rewrite any existing magento helpers.

For example if you want to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare` you need to add

```
<helpers>
    ....
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <compare>Namespace_Module_Helper_Compare</compare>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</helpers>
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: What if I want to add/rewrite a helper in a 'sub-namespace' (not quite sure how to call it), say `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare`? Would `<class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper>` include this as well? How would I call it?

Comment: Answer was updated.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to rewrite two helpers:

1. `enterprise_wishlist` module helper
2. `mage_wishlist` module helper

In my `config.xml` I have added:

```
<helpers>
    <enterprise_wishlist>
        <rewrite>
            <data>Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Data</data>
        </rewrite>
    </enterprise_wishlist>
    <mage_wishlist>
        <rewrite>
            <data>Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Shared_Data</data>
        </rewrite>
    </mage_wishlist>
</helpers>
```

Also don't forget to add:

1. Helper/Data.php

   ```
   <?php
   class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Enterprise_Wishlist_Helper_Data
   {}
   ```
2. Helper/Shared/Data.php

   ```
   <?php
   class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Shared_Data extends Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data
   {}
   ```

In this way you can change.

Comment: Please check before editing @7ochem if the code is correct then editing is not acceptable.