# Mage Adminhtml rewrite problem

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, overrides

It is driving me crazy.
What I want to do is creating a new Action in the controller:

```
Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php
```

I have done the rewrite using that:

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mymodule_resetdownloads before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Resetdownloads_Adminhtml</mymodule_resetdownloads>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

and the class is:

```
require_once (Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales/OrderController.php');
class Mymodule_Resetdownloads_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{

    public function resetAction() {

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        echo $id;
    }


}
```

Now the rewrite works and I know that because if I create another action like viewAction() it uses mine. But my problem is that I can't create a new one. Any idea why? Am I doing something wrong. I am not getting any error from what I have done, it just redirects me to dashboard.

Comment: what url is being called for the reset action?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/sales_order/reset/id/'.$_link->getId(); ?>">Reset Downloads</a>

Comment: Your link should be `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/reset", array('id'=> $_link->getId()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seem to be with your url key, try adding this to your controller (then go to Admin -> Sales -> Order and click on any order #)

To get the admin url use

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/mytest", array('id'=> 1));
```

Try

```
public function mytestAction(){
    echo 'mytestAction()';
}

//
//to be deleted
public function viewAction(){
   echo '<a href ="' . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/mytest", array('order_id'=> 1)) .'">mytest action</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend! My bad! The way I was making the link was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your controller extend the original controller: `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` instead of `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

Comment: Thanks @Marius but it's not that. I made a mistake when I made the question and I corrected that. I used your answer here to double check what I have done: [link]http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/rewrite-controller-magento

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <modules>
                        <Mymodule_Resetdownloads before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Resetdownloads_Adminhtml</Mymodule_Resetdownloads>
                    </modules>
```

Comment: As I said in my question the controller is overrode correctly and if I use the original Actions like viewActions it is using mine.The problem is that I can't create a new Action ! PS I did try that.Still the same.Thanks!